# Why doesn't my dropdown menu work propely when using parallax?

Tags: html, css, parallax

so I'm working on a new parallax webpage for a school project. Now when I hover over my dropdown nav menu, the menu get's really dark and unreadable. And also I can't hover over my dropdown menu anymore because it disappears. I changed the z-index to a higher value but that doens't seem to work. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

[

```css
body, html {
    background-size: cover; 
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-size-adjust: initial;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1,8em;
    color: #666;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;

}


nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0, .8);
    min-width: 1200px; 
}
 
nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none; 
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 210px; 
    height: 50px; 
    opacity: 0.8; 
    line-height: 50px; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 20px; 
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white;
    display: block; 
    z-index: 1; 
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: skyblue; 

}

nav ul li ul li {
    display: none; 

}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block; 
    background: black;
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
}

.pimg1, .pimg2, .pimg3{
    position:relative;
    opacity: 0.95;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    background-attachment:fixed;
}

.pimg1{
 background-image:url(WallFon.com_11296.jpg);
 min-height: 400px;
}

.pimg2{
    background-image:url(isp.jpg);
    min-height: 400px;
}

.pimg3{
    background-image:url(30714.jpg);
    min-height: 400px;
}

.section-dark{
    text-align:center;
    padding:35px 80px;
}

.section-light{
    text-align:center;
    padding:35px 80px;
}

.section-light{
    background-color:#282e34;
    color:#ddd;
}

.section-dark{
    background-color:#282e34;
    color:#ddd;
}

.ptext{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: lightgray;
    font-size:27px; 
    letter-spacing:6px; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.ptext .border{
    background-color:#111;
    color:white; 
    padding:20px; 
}

.ptext .border .trans{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Parallax webpagina</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Home</a></li>
         <li><a>About us</a></li>
         <li><a>Computers</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a>History of computers</a></li>
              <li><a>Types of computers</a></li>
              
            </ul>
            </li>
          </li>
        <li><a>Building</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a>Recommendation build</a></li>
              <li><a>How to build</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

  <div class="pimg1">
   <div class="ptext">
     <span class="border">
       Parallax webpage 
     </span>
    </div> 
  </div>     

     <section class="section-light">
       <h2>Section one</h2>
       <p1>
         Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus deleniti expedita eligendi quos. Autem cum distinctio porro maiores accusamus dignissimos asperiores libero voluptates dolore quaerat qui repudiandae quasi optio ab, accusantium vitae a doloribus earum tenetur animi aliquid delectus modi?
       </p1>
     </section>

     <div class="pimg2">
     <div class="ptext">
       <span class="border trans">
         Two threee
       </span>
      </div> 
    </div>

       <section class="section-dark">
          <h2>Section Two</h2>
          <p1>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus deleniti expedita eligendi quos. Autem cum distinctio porro maiores accusamus dignissimos asperiores libero voluptates dolore quaerat qui repudiandae quasi optio ab, accusantium vitae a doloribus earum tenetur animi aliquid delectus modi?
          </p1>
        </section>    
        
        <div class="pimg3">
        <div class="ptext">
          <span class="border trans">
            Three Section Three
          </span>        
        </div> 
      </div>            

          <section class="section-dark">
              <h2>Section Three</h2>
              <p1>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus deleniti expedita eligendi quos. Autem cum distinctio porro maiores accusamus dignissimos asperiores libero voluptates dolore quaerat qui repudiandae quasi optio ab, accusantium vitae a doloribus earum tenetur animi aliquid delectus modi?
              </p1>
            </section>   

          <div class="pimg1">
          <div class="ptext">
             <span class="border">
               webpageee
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

][1]

Here's picture with the images as background[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgt0j.png

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit with your css. Basically

1. I lowered the z-index of your `.pimg1` to send it behind the navigation dropdown.
2. Added a dark background to your `nav ul li`.
3. Changed your `nav ul li a:hover` to `nav ul li:hover` and added `cursor: pointer` to it.
4. Changed the `nav ul li:hover ul li` to `nav ul li:hover > ul, nav ul li ul:hover`.

I added this summary so it's easier for you to track the changes. Not sure about the colors you wanted but now you can change those appropriately.

```css
body,
html {
  background-size: cover;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size-adjust: initial;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1, 8em;
  color: #666;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  min-width: 1200px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 210px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: skyblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul,
nav ul li ul:hover {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
}

.pimg1,
.pimg2,
.pimg3 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.95;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.pimg1 {
  background-image: url(WallFon.com_11296.jpg);
  min-height: 400px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.pimg2 {
  background-image: url(isp.jpg);
  min-height: 400px;
}

.pimg3 {
  background-image: url(30714jpg);
  min-height: 400px;
}

.section-dark {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 80px;
}

.section-light {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 80px;
}

.section-light {
  background-color: #282e34;
  color: #ddd;
}

.section-dark {
  background-color: #282e34;
  color: #ddd;
}

.ptext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: lightgray;
  font-size: 27px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ptext .border {
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.ptext .border .trans {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Parallax webpagina</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Home</a></li>
         <li><a>About us</a></li>
         <li><a>Computers</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a>History of computers</a></li>
              <li><a>Types of computers</a></li>
              
            </ul>
            </li>
          </li>
        <li><a>Building</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a>Recommendation build</a></li>
              <li><a>How to build</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

  <div class="pimg1">
   <div class="ptext">
     <span class="border">
       Parallax webpage 
     </span>
    </div> 
  </div>     

     <section class="section-light">
       <h2>Section one</h2>
       <p1>
         Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus deleniti expedita eligendi quos. Autem cum distinctio porro maiores accusamus dignissimos asperiores libero voluptates dolore quaerat qui repudiandae quasi optio ab, accusantium vitae a doloribus earum tenetur animi aliquid delectus modi?
       </p1>
     </section>

     <div class="pimg2">
     <div class="ptext">
       <span class="border trans">
         Two threee
       </span>
      </div> 
    </div>

       <section class="section-dark">
          <h2>Section Two</h2>
          <p1>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus deleniti expedita eligendi quos. Autem cum distinctio porro maiores accusamus dignissimos asperiores libero voluptates dolore quaerat qui repudiandae quasi optio ab, accusantium vitae a doloribus earum tenetur animi aliquid delectus modi?
          </p1>
        </section>    
        
        <div class="pimg3">
        <div class="ptext">
          <span class="border trans">
            Three Section Three
          </span>        
        </div> 
      </div>            

          <section class="section-dark">
              <h2>Section Three</h2>
              <p1>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus deleniti expedita eligendi quos. Autem cum distinctio porro maiores accusamus dignissimos asperiores libero voluptates dolore quaerat qui repudiandae quasi optio ab, accusantium vitae a doloribus earum tenetur animi aliquid delectus modi?
              </p1>
            </section>   

          <div class="pimg1">
          <div class="ptext">
             <span class="border">
               webpageee
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The z-index in the image was indeed the problem, I also didn't know about the cursor attribute, so that's also a nice addition. Thanks!